# React: TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...events.map...'). am I passing this set of objects correctly?

Tags: react-native

Now this is something that I had working when I wasn't using the filter or map. And I can't see what might be different in the implementation that might have caused this.

I have an array of events that's been populated from a JSON endpoint

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import Events from "./Events"

class Feed extends Component {

  state = {
  events: [],
  datesarray: []
}

componentDidMount() {
  fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5002/events')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((data) => {

    {/* Orders descending */}
    this.setState({events: data.sort(
           (event1,event2) => -event1.date.localeCompare(event2.date))})

    {/* Places dates into an array */}
    for (var r in data) {
      let eventdate = r.date;

      if (!this.state.datesarray.includes(eventdate)) {
        this.state.datesarray.push(eventdate);
      }

}}
  )
  .catch(console.log)
}
```

On rendering I have a solution which works and renders directly to page. And a second one which attempts to pass the array of objects to a second component.

### Direct render

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="feed">

      <div className="container">
          {this.state.events
            .filter(event => event.date
              .includes('2020-09-08'))
            .map(filteredEvents =>(
                <span>{filteredEvents.title} <br /></span>


              )
            )
          }

      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This produces:
[image]

### Passes to 'Event' component

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="feed">

      <div className="container">
          {this.state.events
            .filter(event => event.date
              .includes('2020-09-08'))
            .map(filteredEvents =>(

                <Events events={filteredEvents} />

              )
            )
          }

      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This produces:

[image]

### The Events Component

I haven't changed this at all since before I added the `map` `filter` functions. I can only think that there's a difference in the way that the `events` array and the `filteredEvents` array are typed or structured. But it's a bit beyond me at the moment.

```
import React from 'react';
import Accordion from 'react-bootstrap/Accordion'
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card'
import TypeTags from './TypeTags'
import LocationTags from './LocationTags'
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import './App.css'


function Events ({events}){


  return (
    <div>

      {events.map((event) => (
        <div className="mt-2">
        <span>{event.title}</span>
        <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0" className="rounded" bsPrefix="event-accordion">
          <Card className="rounded">
            <Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header} eventKey={event.id} className="accordion-title">
              <span className="badge badge-secondary">{event.date}</span><span> </span>
              <span>{event.title}</span>
            </Accordion.Toggle>
            <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={event.id} className="accordion-collapse">

              <Card.Body className="rounded">
              <span>{event.summary}</span><br />
              <span><Link to={`/detail/${event.id}`} >See detail</Link></span>
              <span><TypeTags typeTags={event.tag} /></span>
              <span><LocationTags locationTags={event.location} /></span>
              </Card.Body>
            </Accordion.Collapse>
          </Card>
        </Accordion>

        </div>
      ))}

    </div>
  )

}
export default Events;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake.

The mapping and subsequent call to the `Event` component were to contain a single instance of the event, not an array of events as I had been passing before. As a result of this I need to make a modification to the `Events` component by:

1. Removing the map function `{events.map((event) => (...)`
2. Renaming the variable that was being used in the call to the Event component to `event` for easier reading.

### Updated Render

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="feed">

      <div className="container">
          {this.state.events
            .filter(event => event.date
              .includes('2020-09-08'))
            .map(filteredEvent =>(
                <Events event={filteredEvent} />

              )
            )
          }

      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Updated `Events` component

```
import React from 'react';
import Accordion from 'react-bootstrap/Accordion'
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card'
import TypeTags from './TypeTags'
import LocationTags from './LocationTags'
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import './App.css'


function Events ({event}){


  return (
    <div>


        <div className="mt-2">
        
        <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0" className="rounded" bsPrefix="event-accordion">
          <Card className="rounded">
            <Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header} eventKey={event.id} className="accordion-title">
              <span className="badge badge-secondary">{event.date}</span><span> </span>
              <span>{event.title}</span>
            </Accordion.Toggle>
            <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={event.id} className="accordion-collapse">

              <Card.Body className="rounded">
              <span>{event.summary}</span><br />
              <span><Link to={`/detail/${event.id}`} >See detail</Link></span>
              <span><TypeTags typeTags={event.tag} /></span>
              <span><LocationTags locationTags={event.location} /></span>
              </Card.Body>
            </Accordion.Collapse>
          </Card>
        </Accordion>

        </div>


    </div>
  )

}
export default Events;
```